# function mysql_fetch_row returns NULL, which disables login

Tags: php

In this following code var_dump($row) returns NULL, while $sql, $conn and $result seem to be ok. 
New to PHP, and cant figure out what is the problem. Thanks for help!

```
<?php

session_start();
include_once 'dbh.inc.php';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
$pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);
if (empty($uid) || empty($pwd)) {
    header("Location: ../index.php?login=empty");
    exit();
} else {
    //Check if username exists USING PREPARED STATEMENTS
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM us WHERE user_username='$uid'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if($result) {
        var_dump($result);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        var_dump($row);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        if ($pwd != $row['user_password']) {
            header("Location: ../index.php?login=passerror");
            exit();
        } else {
            //Set SESSION variables and log user in
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
            $_SESSION['user_email'] = $row['user_email'];
            $_SESSION['user_username'] = $row['user_username'];
            header("Location: ../index.php");
            exit();
            }
        }
    }
}
} else {
    header("Location: ../index.php?login=buttonerror");
    exit();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super experienced either, but try this and let me know.

change

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
```

to

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your code, it's works fine, please change the db and check it once

you are  passing $conn in mysql_real_escape_string

```
$uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
```